# Pie-Chart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, pie-chart

I'm using  [pie_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart)   library to draw `pie-chart` in my flutter project.

Does anyone know how to add the text in the center of pie, and increase the  arc width?

**Edit**

```
 return PieChart(
                              dataMap: dataMap,
                              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                              chartRadius:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.7,
                              showChartValuesInPercentage: true,
                              showChartValues: true,
                              showChartValuesOutside: true,
                              chartValueBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                              colorList: colorList,
                              showLegends: true,
                              legendPosition: LegendPosition.right,
                              decimalPlaces: 1,
                              showChartValueLabel: true,
                              chartType: ChartType.ring,
                              centerText: "Title",
                            );
```

Comment: you can use ``Stack`` place your chart and text widget under ``Positioned`` to add a text on the chart. Else you can fork the package and modify the source as per your need.

Comment: @OMiShah yes, I using `Stack`, but the text position slightly changed when I run using other devices.

Comment: then the best bet will be to fork the package and modify it. :)

Comment: @OMiShah but can't find the way to modify

Comment: i will try modifying it and let you know asap

Comment: @OMiShah bro any update for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fork](https://github.com/apgapg/pie_chart) or get `chart_painter.dart` and `pie_chart.dart` from [here](https://github.com/apgapg/pie_chart/tree/master/lib/src)

**1. chart_painter.dart**

add an optional parameter `centerText` of type `String`

```
 final String centerText;

  PieChartPainter(
    //..
    this.centerText
  }) { //..
```

Create a method

```
  void _drawCenterText(Canvas canvas, double side) {
    final radius = side * 0.5;
    final xy = radius * math.sin((_totalAngle * _subParts.last)) / 8;

    _drawName(canvas, centerText, xy, xy, side);
  }
```

Call it from `paint`

```
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
     //..
    if(centerText != null) {
      _drawCenterText(canvas, side);
    }

  }
```

**2. PieChart.dart**

Do the same for `PieChart.dart`

```
 final String centerText;

 PieChart({
    //..
    this.centerText,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

On `_getChart` method

```
 _getChart() {
    return Flexible(
      //..
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: PieChartPainter(
              //..
              centerText: widget.centerText
            ),
            child: AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 1),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**3. In You application**

```
PieChart(
      //..           
      chartType: ChartType.disc,
      centerText: "Your Center Text Here"
  )
```

[image: pie chart with text at center]
[image: ring chart with text at center]

Comment: I using `ChartType.ring`, but the text is not in center

Comment: @JohnJoe Looks pretty center to me. check the updated screenshot.

Comment: Is it caused by the pie chart parameters?

Comment: Have you changed your code according to this answer?

Comment: Check the updated _drawCenterText method. It will handle the issue

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot. If I want to add a sub-title below the title, do you know how?

Comment: You can follow the same pattern with smaller font size.

Comment: Why the title show one time in first chart, but show two title in second chart? Here the image   https://imgur.com/EiwAunO

Comment: do you  know why?

Comment: Thanks..I will try your answer later :) Just wonder is it possible to remove the background grey color for the center text ? O.o

Comment: you can, play with the chart_painter.dart file yourself.