# Flutter pie chart as a ring with legend inside circle

Tags: flutter, dart

What packages to use if we want to create ring pie chart, like in image below.  Legend must be inside circle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pie_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart). There is a similar picture in the package document. You can customize it.

**Edit:**

There is another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59458861/10659482), how you can center text.

[image]